# Synonyms of "such that"

Tags: synonyms

I found myself writing *such that* many times already. Which synonyms would be adequate? Here is a typical example:

> For theory 1 Eq. (1.1.1) can be written as ... , while for theory 2
>   *A* must be replaced by *B*, **such that** ...

Comment: Use *such that* throughout, as many times as required. The context is Math, where *such that* has a **specific meaning** that cannot be brought about by another expression. The reader expects you to use well-recognized phrases so they could concentrate more on the equations or whatever else is there, rather on than the nuances of language. Do not worry about great writing style here, readability is what matters.

Comment: @Kris, I liked you comment, perhaps you can post it as an answer...

Comment: See also: [math.se]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use *such that* throughout, as many times as required.

The context is Math, where [such that](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SuchThat.html)<sup>*</sup> has a **specific meaning** that cannot be brought about by another expression.

> A condition used in the definition of a mathematical object, commonly denoted : or |. For example, the rationals [image: Q] can be defined by
>     [image: Z]
> read as "the set of all [image: p/q] such that [image: q!=0] and [image: p,q in Z]."

The reader expects you to use well-recognized phrases so they could concentrate more on the equations or whatever else is there, rather than on the nuances of language.

Do not worry about great writing style here, readability is what matters.

<sup>*</sup><sub>[source: Weisstein, Eric W. "Such That." From MathWorld – A Wolfram Web Resource.]</sub>

Comment: "It was a dark and stormy night, when A must be replaced by B..."

Comment: Huh, @Oldcat ? I'm curious. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_was_a_dark_and_stormy_night